# How to use AWS Federation Login with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-iam

I have a laravel application where I want to integrate AWS Federation login. I have my policies and groups setup correctly in AWS. I want the user to click on a button, and then the user will be redirected to the aws console page where they are already logged in using aws federation. I want to use three variables, AccessKey, SecretKey, and GroupName. How do I achieve this? I am supposed to use STS client and getFederationToken methods but I'm not sure how to fully combine everything to get the correct SignInToken and pass it to the.

The login URL I'm trying to use: [https://signin.aws.amazon.com/federation?Action=login&SigninToken={SignInToken}&Issuer={Issuer}&Destination={Destination}](https://signin.aws.amazon.com/federation?Action=login&SigninToken=%7BSignInToken%7D&Issuer=%7BIssuer%7D&Destination=%7BDestination%7D)

I already have the issuer and destination correctly setup, however I can't seem to get the SignInToken.

```
    // Create a new AWS STS client
    $client = new StsClient([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region'  => 'us-west-2',
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => 'ACCESS_KEY',
            'secret' => 'SECRET_KEY',
        ],
    ]);

    $groupName = 'GROUP_NAME';
    $policy = json_encode([
            'Version' => '2012-10-17',
            'Statement' => [
                [
                    'Effect' => 'Allow',
                    'Action' => '*',
                    'Resource' => '*'
                ]
            ]
        ]);

    $result = $client->getFederationToken(
        [
            'Name' => 'username',
            'Policy' => $policy,
            'DurationSeconds' => 3600,
            'Tags' => [
                [
                    'Key' => 'group',
                    'Value' => $groupName
                ],
            ],
        ]
    );

    $token = $result['Credentials']['SessionToken'];
    $signInToken = urlencode($token);
    $finalUrl = $loginBaseUrl . $signInToken . $issuer . $destination;
```

This is my laravel controller. The URL redirects me to the AWS page but it says that there is a problem with the SignInToken.

It's also worth noting that I'm trying to translate this from code in C#, so this is already done and the setup on AWS side is correct, I'm just not sure how to generate the proper signintoken.

Answer (score 0):

Install the AWS SDK for PHP using composer:

```
composer require aws/aws-sdk-php
```

In your controller, create an instance of the Aws\Sts\StsClient class and use the assumeRoleWithWebIdentity method to authenticate the user and generate temporary security credentials.

```
use Aws\Sts\StsClient;

class FederationController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $client = new StsClient([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region' => 'us-west-2'
        ]);

        $result = $client->assumeRoleWithWebIdentity([
            'RoleArn' => 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/federated_role',
            'RoleSessionName' => 'session_name',
            'WebIdentityToken' => $request->input('token'),
            'DurationSeconds' => 3600
        ]);

        // Use the temporary security credentials returned by the assumeRoleWithWebIdentity method to access AWS resources.
    }
}
```

You should now have the temporary security credentials for the authenticated

Comment: But how do I get the role arn and the web identity token from the sts client?